# String declaration segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, cs50

After declaring a string, I get a segmentation fault.
I do not know how to address this error — can you explain?

Code version 1 (using `typedef char *string;` from `cs50.h`):

```
int main (int argc, string argv[])
{
    string key = argv[1]; 
    checkKey(key, argc);
}

int checkKey(string text, int n)
{
    //check if text is alphabetical and if argc has the desired amount of command-line elements 
}
```

Code version 2:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    printf("%d elements in argc and %s in argv[1]\n", argc, argv[1]);
    char* key = argv[1];
}
```

Comment: where is `string` declared? is it C++? or a typedef? and when you call your main do you pass parameters?

Comment: Did you define `string`somewhere? How do you call your program? If there is no parameter, argv[1] will not be valid.

Comment: Check `argc` before you access any `argv`.

Comment: string is defined at cs50.h (basically is a char*) and I will check for argc before assuming argv[1] has some content. Thanks for the inputs.

Comment: string is a typedef ,which is char*

Comment: Never access beyond `argv[0]` without first checking `argc` to assure the command line parameter actually exists.

Comment: the posted code is using nothing from `cs50.h` nor is it using anything from `ctype.h`.  It is a very bad idea to include header files that are not actually used.

Comment: when posting an edit, DO NOT modify the original code.  Otherwise, early comments make no sense.

Comment: the posted code will cause the compiler to raise a warning message about the variable `key` being set but not used.

Comment: *using `typedef char *string;` from cs50.h* -> PLEASE DON'T!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run your program without command line arguments, it receives the value `1` for `argc` and an array `argv` of size 2 with the name of the program in `argv[0]` and `NULL` in `argv[1]`.

If your function `charkKey()` dereferences the pointer it receives as its first argument, you invoke undefined behavior, which can result in a segmentation fault.